# Sorting an array using custom logic

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, .net-2.0

I have an array which I want to sort using some custom logic.

```
new string[] {"bRad", "Charles", "sam", "lukE", "vIctor"}
```

Now I want to sort this according to positional occurrence of capital letters in a string. If the first letter is capital then ignore others. If two strings have capital letters at same  position then sort them alphabetically. If there are no capital letters in the string then it obviously goes to the end of the list. Performance is a key factor, there's going to be huge amount data on which this is tested.

Output should be

```
new string[] {"Charles", "vIctor", "bRad", "lukE", "sam"}
```

Explanation:

`Charles` comes first because it has capital letter at first position.
`vIctor` comes second because it has capital letter at second position
`bRad`  comes third because it has capital letter at second position but comes after `I`
`lukE`  comes first because it has capital letter at fourth position
`sam` comes last because there are no capital letters in any position.

I am restricted to .NET 2.0. Please help.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Is it always going to be just ASCII characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach for performance: You can use a custom comparer that follows the capitalization rules. For speed you can use two integer arrays each the size of the alphabet that you are using (26 different upper case characters in the simple case of ASCII) that keep track of character counts of capitalized letters, if the count for all the capitalized letters found are equal for both words you can just compare the strings themselves:

```
public class CapitalizerComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        int[] xCount = new int[26];
        int[] yCount = new int[26];

        foreach(char c in x)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(c))
                xCount[c-'A']++;
        }

        foreach (char c in y)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(c))
                yCount[c-'A']++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < xCount.Length; i++)
        {
            if(xCount[i] > yCount[i])
                return -1;
            else if(yCount[i] > xCount[i])
                return 1;
        }
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

Since according to your rules the position of the capitalized character is irrelevant you have to look at all characters of both words to make a decision. Above algorithm hence should be optimal and O(n+m).

```
//use case:
var input = new string[] { "bRad", "Charles", "sam", "lukE", "vIctor" };
Array.Sort(input, new CapitalizerComparer());
```

Output:

```
Charles
lukE
vIctor
bRad
sam
```

Comment: There is a slight change in the problem I posted. The order will be upon the at what position the letters are capitalized. Like first letter capitalized will come first(if there are more than one then sort then alphabetically and so on).

Comment: @SohamDasgupta: I don't quite understand what you mean. Is this a change from the already posted question or an existing requirement that is not met? If it is the former I'd encourage you to post a new question otherwise existing answers won't apply anymore.

Comment: I've updated the question according to the new logic. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. Any further help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I would be deeply obliged if you can answer my new question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be broken into some smaller discrete pieces.  First, you need to identify the capitals.  This can be done using RegEx:

```
Regex rg = new Regex("[A-Z]");
MatchCollection mc = rg.Matches(crazyString);
```

http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2009/10/01/Parsing-Capital-Letters.aspx

Next you need to write the function that does the sorting.  You should run the regex against each string to find the capitals.  Then compare the capitals to sort.

If you want to do this using OOP you should make a class that implements the `IComparable` interface http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727

```
public MyClass : IComparable
{
  int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj)
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest suing the [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for this. You can implement it in your own class, and provide your own custom logic for sorting.  You'd do this by specifying the Comparer in an Array.Sort() method call: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f.aspx